# Should I still use With(NoLock) in SQL Server queries?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write some queries to fetch data from database. I used to use With(NoLock) to prevent SQL Server from placing shared locks on database. And recently a friend of mine told me that the default behavior now is that it doesn't put any lock on reading data.

However, I can't find a clean explanation for this.
Should I still use With(NoLock) in SQL Server?

Comment: Probably ask your friend to point you to some articles as a proof.

Comment: This is only the default behaviour if you enable RCSI (which is not the default except on Azure) - but you shouldn't be using `With(NoLock)` routinely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`WITH (NOLOCK)` behaves the same as setting the transaction isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED`, just its scope is different.

However, keep in mind that SQL Server is allowed to use a different isolation level depending on the type of query you are running. (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and other write operations have to run under at least `READ COMMITTED`).

Your friend is not right, SQL Server will acquire at least a schema lock during read operations on the table to prevent changes in the table's structure. This lock will be applied to the table even if you use `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level or the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint.

In general, I would avoid using the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint. You have less control when using the table hint. Use `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level for the connection if dirty reads are acceptable.

You can always change the isolation level of the connection, but you cannot dynamically remove the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint. This is especially true when you use `WITH (NOLOCK)` on each and every table.

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` is not deprecated for `SELECT` queries.  IMO the  table hint gives you *more* control because it is targeted at the specific table and doesn't apply to every table in every statement.

Comment: In that terms, you are right, you can scope it to a table, but you cannot change it easily when it is needed. And if you use it for all tables, I don't see the point, you can simply change the isolation level. I would avoid to use it, but yeah, sometimes it is necessary.

Comment: And yeah, you are right, `WITH (NOLOCK)` is not deprecated just the table hints without the `WITH` keyword. My fault, removed from the answer

Answer (score 2):

I found in Microsoft documentation the following statement which warns to use `NOLOCK` and `READUNCOMMITTED` hints in query

> Note: Support for use of the `READUNCOMMITTED` and NOLOCK hints in the FROM clause that apply to the target table of an UPDATE or DELETE statement will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these hints in this context in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them.

You can check the documentation from the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table for more information. There is no mention of being it the default behaviour.

Comment: OP is asking for just fetching data which is quite common to use `with (nolock)` hint with select statements. However the warning you referenced is only related to `update` and `delete` statements.

Answer (score 2):

[Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15)

Deprecated feature

> Specifying NOLOCK or READUNCOMMITTED in the FROM clause of an UPDATE
>   or DELETE statement.

Replacement

> Remove the NOLOCK or READUNCOMMITTED table hints from the FROM
>   clause.

Feature name

> NOLOCK or READUNCOMMITTED in UPDATE or DELETE

Comment: Keep in mind that the original question was about "WITH (NOLOCK)" hint on SELECT statements, while what's being depreciated is NOLOCK on UPDATE/INSERT statements, and on SELECT statements without the "WITH" keyword. Therefore "SELECT * FROM abc NOLOCK" is being depreciated and replaced with "SELECT * FROM abc WITH (NOLOCK)".